# Type of beadpanel to use for wainscoting in a bathroom

Tags: bathroom

We're renovating our bathroom and we're planning to do wainscoting.

I found some MDF beadboards whose moisture rating is "moisture-resistant". Can I trust that in a bathroom (assuming I use the proper primer and paint for it) or do I have to go with a vinyl beadboard instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual wooden beadboard has been used in bathrooms for decades. It needs to be well primed and painted to do well, and it probably should not be used on a tub surround. MDF shyould be significantly more moisture resistant than wood, again if properly prepared.

There is no question that vinyl would be *much more* moisture resistant than either wood or MDF. But many people do not like the look of vinyl.

If you application is not especially demanding, you are probably fine with MDF.

Comment: Exactly what I wished to hear, because I don't think I wanted to work with vinyl. And no, I won't be using it as a bath surround :)